# active window without showing it or bringing it to top

Tags: java, window, jna, user32

I want a function that I can't find wish allow to activate a window, without showing it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `activate a window`? Is this window something like a `JFrame` or is it any window that happens to be running on the same computer as your program?

Comment: any window in the computer why I use JNA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer:

a minimized window can't be active, and there is a way to communcate with hidden windows (if not minimized using messages)

Answer (score 0):

If this window is a subclass of [java.awt.Window](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html) you can call [setVisible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setVisible%28boolean%29) to hide it.